# Sum of PCA principal components

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, pca, dimensionality-reduction, multidimensional-scaling

### Short

I wonder is it possible to sum the principal components together to obtain a score? For example, PC1 + PC2.

### Details

I got the below dataframe:

| admin_username | sales | sign | book | team_sales | team_sign | team_book | sub | turnover |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ada | 400000 | 9 | 0 | 670000 | 31 | 2 | 12 | 0 |
| billy | 85000 | 6 | 1 | 168000 | 16 | 2 | 7 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | --- | ... | ... |

In order to compare the users' performance, I performed the PCA. I set the `n_components=0.8` that said I wanted the PCs can cover at least 80% variance.  Moreover, the values are normalized by `StandardScaler`, I will state the normalized values as `norm(value)`.Below is the result:

```
explained_variance_ratio_ : [0.47 0.2  0.14]
components_ : [[ 4.72509076e-01  2.54901887e-01  4.91158593e-01  1.07551283e-01
  -0.00000000e+00  5.10704453e-01  4.38406087e-01  7.70533828e-02]
 [-2.14573422e-01 -2.39650814e-01 -4.01742075e-02 -6.93156538e-01
  -2.77555756e-17  2.05160081e-01  2.48732242e-01  5.57213957e-01]
 [-5.75108585e-02  7.18532379e-01 -2.11472525e-01  1.89615365e-01
  -5.55111512e-17 -1.47130170e-01 -1.00609858e-01  6.06596633e-01]]
```

Then the PC1 of `ada` is calculated by `0.472509076 * norm(sales) + 0.254901887 * norm(sign) + ... +  0.438406087 * norm(sub) + 0.0770533828 * norm(turnover)`
For PC2, it is similar to the calculation of PC1, just using different coefficients as stated by `components[1]`

As a result, I will get both PC1 and PC2 these 2 values of `ada`. However, I would like to determine the users' performance by just one number rather than two. Would it be possible to simply add PC1 and PC2 together? or 0.47 * PC1 + 0.2 * PC2?

Comment: I just think it sounds a bit strange to just simply add them to generate a meaningful score that indicates the performance.

If it is possible, then which way to do the summation? PC1 + PC2 or  0.47 * PC1 + 0.2 * PC2 ?

Comment: Each of your principal components now represents a standardised value that will tend mostly to be between -2 and +2 and that each capture a completely separate aspect of your data.  Now, could it make sense to combine them into a total score?  Well, it *could* but it would certainly be arbitrary and would have to be a matter of judgment of what those two separate things represent (if indeed they cleanly represent anything) and whether increases in both of those things (if they do) definitely represent increases in the thing you would consider your score to represent...

Comment: One possible option that might help you to get some insight into what is captured in your PCs is to rotate them (e.g. varimax).  Now each of the rotated components represents something completely different to what they did before, but the goal of the rotation is to try to pull out components that you *might* be able to assign meaning to by trying to associate specific component with specific original variables, so there is some hope that that approach might help you to assign meaning to your components, and then decide if it makes sense to combine them in some arbitrary way.

Comment: **Why**  do you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve? What is this "score" supposed to measure?

Comment: TO use a score to indicate the performance of the user in both individual and team aspects. So the columns 'sales, sign, book' are counted as individual performance while the left columns are counted as team performance. 

Since the PC1 only covers ~40% variance, it is not perfer to only use PC1 score to indicate the performance. Therefore, I consider the PC2 also as it covers additional 20% variance, I will get two scores at the same time, however, I just want one score to represent and wonder is it good to let PC1 + PC2 to achieve a total score.

Comment: I don't think so.  Adding them suggests that they have the same directionality (where, say, a high value is "good"), and there is nothing in the method to guarantee that.

Comment: @Arthur Then what way do you suggest in order to achieve my goal?

Comment: @PhilAssheton Are there some codes for performing varimax rotation in PCA?

Comment: If you're looking for a single variable that captures the majority of variance among a set of variables, then the first principal component accomplishes that.  I don't think adding principal components will improve on this.  If you want to consider more than one variable to describe the larger set, you can consider the subsequent principal components as well.  If you have a response variable and you're trying to relate predictors to this response, then PCA might not be the right method for you, and you should consider a supervised method instead, like PLS, elastic net, or random forest.

Comment: @PhilAssheton Thanks for your suggestion. Indeed, there is sth meaningful to see after performing varimax rotation.